# We need your help to clean up Web Apps!  

Tags: discussion, clean-up

Web Apps needs your help!  In honor of Web Apps' anniversary celebration, we're cleaning up questions and/or answers that are `not answers`, or are closed that have no future value whatsoever.

So...what can you do?  You can:

1. Flag for moderator attention
2. Post the URL in the community wiki answer below.

**Cheers to Web Applications birthday!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a list of questions that are candidates for deletion - mostly closed for various reasons (too localized, off-topic, not constructive, etc.).  When a question has been burned with fire, use strikethrough (`<s>foo</s>`).

**Batch #1:**

> <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20298/video-site-server-system-design</s>
>   [Is Google Apps good enough for business?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/211/is-google-apps-good-enough-for-business)
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/399/sync-my-google-buzz-to-facebook</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/283/what-should-people-know-about-how-to-blog</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/311/how-can-i-use-the-goo-gl-shortener-service</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/545/is-there-any-tips-and-tricks-for-google-buzz</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15587/whatever-happened-to-parkinganytime-com</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15386/free-helpdesk-solution-sharing-a-mailbox-on-google-apps-free-edition</s> 
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18729/is-there-a-web-mail-service-that-offers-smtp-without-ssl</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/when-to-not-post-to-both-public-and-extended-circles</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18784/web-based-git-repo-viewer</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18733/any-suggestions-for-an-online-card-creator</s>
>   [How does Google Docs differ essentially from other services like Dropbox](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19187/how-does-google-docs-differ-essentially-from-other-services-like-dropbox)

**Batch #2:**

> <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20226/video-intro-technologies-best-practices</s>
>    <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20306/i-cannot-open-facebook-page</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20372/what-major-web-based-email-providers-offer-autosave</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20274/deploy-django-application-in-the-cloud</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20236/a-leader-board-of-songs-films-apps-and-books-bought-by-your-friends</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13655/hotmail-login-page-showing-blank-page</s>  
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11766/how-to-use-igoogle-themes-in-my-webpage</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19691/how-to-translate-a-web-app-to-my-language-with-scripts</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20111/website-with-integrated-apps</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20187/error-with-plugin</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20109/getting-the-alias-http-www-facebook-com-yourapp</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16107/crm-with-strong-integration-for-mac-mail-and-ios</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16381/automation-applications-for-facebook</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16682/web-picture-viewer</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16889/how-to-filter-my-visits-in-google-analytics</s>
>   <s>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17036/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-develop-web-applications-mashups-using-amazon-product</s>