# question disappeared

Tags: support, deleted-questions

My webapps [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20372/what-major-web-based-email-providers-offer-autosave) seems to have disappeared, I'm assuming it was deleted? It would be nice to be able to see this information somewhere, how can I learn what if anything I've done wrong if I get no feedback?

--added after ChrisF's helpful answer--

Ok, so `not constructive` is defined as:
`This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.`

I don't really see how this fits, seemed pretty straightforward to me. Unless there is some confusion as to what defines a "major" email provider? Then I could have been requested to reword my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was closed as "Not Constructive" as it was asking for just a list of email providers. In this format there is no real correct/incorrect answer (just a poll of services) which does not fit with the StackExchange Format.

If on the other hand, you wanted to figure out how to turn on auto-save in Hotmail that would be a good question.

The deletion was done based on a clean-up [We need your help to clean up Web Apps!](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/983/we-need-your-help-to-clean-up-web-apps)   asked by another user. Normally we wait longer to delete a closed question giving the user time to review it and request a vote to reopen. In this case the deletion happened sooner than normal.

Comment: I see your point, although the details listed under "Not Constructive" don't really apply, but I'm assuming they're are more detailed FAQs on the main stackoverflow site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it was deleted.

The question was originally closed as "Not Constructive". See the [FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#close) for more information on why it might have been closed.

We normally leave closed questions on the site for a while to give the owner chance to revise the post in case it can be brought on topic or made constructive.

There are occasions when a question will be deleted sooner rather than later, but another moderator performed the deletion so you'll have to wait until they see this question and respond.